# KeyError: 'zope' when starting some Python apps (supervisord, gunicorn, …)

Tags: python, gunicorn, supervisord

I'm not sure if the issue is actually related to supervisord but here is what I get when I try to launch it. It looks like a bit like the issue would be related to Python2 itself…

```
$ supervisord
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/supervisord", line 5, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 2727, in <module>
    add_activation_listener(lambda dist: dist.activate())
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 700, in subscribe
    callback(dist)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 2727, in <lambda>
    add_activation_listener(lambda dist: dist.activate())
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 2230, in activate
    map(declare_namespace, self._get_metadata('namespace_packages.txt'))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 1815, in declare_namespace
    path = sys.modules[parent].__path__
KeyError: 'zope'
```

My memory might be betraying me but I feel like remembering it happened to me when trying to launch another program too, but I don't remember which atm. [1]

I use supervisord to monitore if one process crash and restart it automatically, but if it crashes continuously, it gives up and I have to kill supervisord and restart it manually. It used to work but not anymore.

**EDIT:** [1] Also happens when I try to launch gunicorn.

```
$ /var/www/bin/gunicorn -b 127.0.0.1:5000 index:app
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/www/bin/gunicorn", line 5, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
  File "/var/www/lib/python3.3/site-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 3027, in <module>
    add_activation_listener(lambda dist: dist.activate())
  File "/var/www/lib/python3.3/site-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 741, in subscribe
    callback(dist)
  File "/var/www/lib/python3.3/site-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 3027, in <lambda>
    add_activation_listener(lambda dist: dist.activate())
  File "/var/www/lib/python3.3/site-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 2514, in activate
    list(map(declare_namespace, self._get_metadata('namespace_packages.txt')))
  File "/var/www/lib/python3.3/site-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 2082, in declare_namespace
    path = sys.modules[parent].__path__
KeyError: 'zope'
```

**EDIT 2:** Seems to be linked to this issue: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/zope.app.pagetemplate/+bug/851038 … but I'm not sure what to do about it. **EDIT EDIT:** Well maybe not, it is 4y old.

Yes I do use Ubuntu Server as well.

Comment: A package in the `zope` namespace is b0rken, somehow. Did you delete something like `zope.interface` or similar actions?

Comment: Seems like `supervisord` is not installed correctly. Try to reinstall it.

Comment: @Valijon: no, another package isn't.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Didn't delete anything, or not that I know.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Should I delete the [supervisord] tag as it seems it isn't related to `supervisord`?

Comment: I'm fine with leaving it; I'm sorry that I am short on time right now to help you figure this out, but it's a [`setuptools` namespace package](https://pythonhosted.org/setuptools/setuptools.html#namespace-packages) that is broken here. Looking at your traceback, it is a `gunicorn` dependency.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Yeah, I'm a bit lost here, thanks in advance if you can help me, whenever you have time, buddy!

Comment: Execute this: `exec("import sys\nfor name in sys.builtin_module_names:\n\tprint(name)")` If you do not see `zope` module, install it both for python 2.7 and 3.3 [https://pypi.python.org/pypi/zope.interface/4.1.2](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/zope.interface/4.1.2)

Comment: @Valijon I do not have it. I hoped I could just `pip install zope` but it just raised the same error. :) Now to figure how to install it manually, not sure yet… EDIT: halp… Do I really need to compile it myself? Any workaround if I have the choice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on a [long discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/6?m=23212794#23212794), the problem is that you've messed with your env in such a way that some python installations on your system are getting confused.

Your `.bashrc` file contains the line `export PYTHONPATH=/usr/local/lib/python3.3/dist-packages/`.  However, *all* Pythons will use this path, even Python 2.

You installed supervisor and gunicorn with apt, and these versions use python2.  When you run `gunicorn`, that command uses python2, which picks up the PYTHONPATH with Python 3 specific stuff on it.  Something along the line tries to inspect the path and gets confused somehow.

Remove the line in your `.bashrc` file modifying the PYTHONPATH.